# Is there a performance penalty for 3-byte vertex attributes in a shader?

Tags: graphics, vulkan

I want to have a vertex input format like so:

```
layout (location = 0) in vec3 position; // Format VK_FORMAT_R8G8B8_SFLOAT
layout (location = 1) in vec3 normal; // Format VK_FORMAT_R8G8B8_UNORM
layout (location = 2) in vec3 tangent; // Format VK_FORMAT_R8G8B8_UNORM
```

The position in the vertex buffer will be 3 floats, so take up 12 bytes.
The normal attribute will be three chars, -127 to +127, and glsl will read them as normalised floats (-1 to +1).
So too will be the tangent. As far as I understand it the 'vec3' in glsl isn't saying that the type read in if 3 floats, but rather dependent on the format given when creating the input layout description and given to the shader pipeline. This essentially means that normal takes up three bytes, and then tangent vec3 begins on a byte boundary not 4-byte aligned. I didn't want to use vec4 because then that would be a waste of space.

In order to use vec4s I can do:

```
layout (location = 1) in vec4 normal; // Format VK_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM
layout (location = 2) in vec4 tangent; // Format VK_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM
```

Then the w component of normal can have the x component of the tangent, and the x and y components of tangent can have the y and z components of the tangent, leaving me two extra bytes to use for other stuff, but then I have the problem of being able to store, for example a 16 bit number in the last two bytes, as the shader reads the bytes in as normalised float.

Is there a performance penalty to pack the normal and tangent more closely together like this as two vec3s, which each take 3 bytes each?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, **implementation dependent**.

Second, the penalty would probably be negligable for most cases.

Third, *speculation*, I'd imagine that the HW will load the whole cache line containing the required data, and if the data isn't aligned the way its ready to be transformed (e.g. if a thread can only operate on a 4 aligned data, and non-aligned would cut it in pieces) it would simply do some bitshifting and ORing, adding some *compute* overhead.

So its probably a memory(space, throughput)-compute(fl/iops) trade-off.